# Where to store shadow colors in ThemeData?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

1- I have a container with a box shadow and that shadow has a different color depending on the theme. Where exactly do I store the shadow color in ThemeData? I stored the container’s color in `canvasColor` but I am not sure where to put the shadow color. So I can easily do Theme.of(context)...

2- When making separate themes, is it ok if I do `return ThemeData(myStuff);` instead of doing `ThemeData().copyWith(myStuff);`? Or is copyWith the recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually you don't change shadows by theme. If so.. you can create you own class and store shadows there.

   ```
   class MyShadows {
     static const primaryShadow =
       Shadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 3, offset: Offset(2, 3));

    static const secondaryShadow =
      Shadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 3, offset: Offset(2, 3));
   }

   ...
   Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [MyShadows.primaryShadow]),
   );
   ```
2. It's okay. When you do ThemeData(). copyWith(yourStuff) - you create new instance of ThemeData, and then create another instance from it, by calling copyWith

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MUI 3 then add shadow in colorScheme

```dart
MaterialApp(
  //...

  theme: ThemeData(
    // If this is true, `Theme.of(context).shadowColor` will not work
    // Instead use, `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.shadow`
    useMaterial3: true, 
    
    shadowColor: Color(0xFF000000), // works if useMaterial3 is false
    
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(someColor).copyWith(
      shadow: Color(0xFFABCDEF) // works for useMaterial3: true,
    )
  )
)
```